# Data binding onClick in a fragment using interface

Tags: android-studio, android-databinding

I recently started working with data binding and I ran into a problem that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to use an interface to handle when a button is clicked but it keeps on giving me a cannot find setter attribute for onClick on the button.

In my XML file I have

```
        android:onClick="@{() -> iCalculatorFragment.onButtonClicked()}"
```

In my onCreateView in my Fragment I have

```
mFragmentCalculatorBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);
mFragmentCalculatorBinding.setICalculatorFragment(this);
```

My interface method is

```
void onButtonClicked();
```

Side notes:

Inside the xml the autocomplete comes up for other methods of the interface but not the button click one. Not sure if that means anything.

Also building has drastically slowed down since using data binding. Sometimes it takes over 10 minutes to build and it ends due to an error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Please add your full code of `fragment` and `xml` to question